What's the easiest way to generate a numpy array of index values in Python?
Given some data in a numpy array, what is the most efficient way to generate a similar numpy array containing the index values?
I considered a couple of possibilities, the details for which are provided below. I'm wondering if there is a simpler method.
Btw: This question is not intended to be opinion based. I provide the examples below to illustrate the point. However, I would guess that there is a standard numpy function which given an input numpy array will produce an array of the same length with the index values of each element. For example:

If the input is [3.14, 3.15, 3.16] such a function would return [0, 1, 2]. (Both objects being numpy arrays.

1. numpy.linspace
numpy.linspace(0, len(data_array), len(data_array), endpoint=False)

This can be modified slightly to return integer values rather than floating point values if this suits the problem domain.
numpy.linspace(0, len(data_array), len(data_array), endpoint=False, dtype=Int)

2. enumerate
enumerate can be used in various forms. I prefer the form using map.
numpy.array([index for (index, _) in enumerate(data_array)])

numpy.array(list(map(lambda pair: pair[0], enumerate(data_array)))

3. numpy.indices
This one is kind of ugly because of the additional comma required to create a tuple.
numpy.indices((len(data_array),))[0]

Each of the above methods returns the correct values. However each is somewhat cumbersome for such a simple task.
4. numpy.arange
Thanks to the suggestions in the comments.
numpy.arange(len(data_array))

or
numpy.array(range(len(data_array)))


I'm not sure what good an array of indices is here, what problem are you solving? And is it worth obsessing over so many different ways to perform a trivial task? Something banal like np.array(range(len(price_data))) does exactly what you ask?

Btw, "most efficient way" (question body) != "easiest way" (title). In fact, it is common for the two to be rather the opposite of each other. There are certainly faster solution than np.arange but pretty complicated ones for such a basic thing. It is good tread-off though.

Yes, something like arange makes much more sense. These are all 1 liners, but my instinct was there should be a trivial way to do it. arange is that thing.

shape is already a tuple.
numpy.indices(data_array.shape)

Other toys to explore, list(np.ndindex(data_array.shape), list(np.ndenumerate(data_array), and np.r_[:len(data_array)].
